# How to edit Jhipster Spring database

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, liquibase

I'm currently working in a Spring project generated by Jhipster. Sometime i have to change my entity (domain) so every times, i have to change the liquibase changelog file and drop the database. So is there anyway like i just have to change my domain file and the liquibase auto re-generated changelog for me.

ex: this is
[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvNBT.png)

every time i want to change my entity i have to change my domain file, i have to change my liquibase changelog file too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `jhipster entity YourEntity` and it will make that changes for you. If you have created the application by importing a JDL file, you can import it again to update the generated source code.

> **Updating an existing entity**
>
> The entity configuration is saved in a specific .json file, in the
> .jhipster directory. So if you run the sub-generator again, using an
> existing entity name, you can update or regenerate the entity.
>
> When you run the entity sub-generator for an existing entity, you will
> be asked a question ‘Do you want to update the entity? This will
> replace the existing files for this entity, all your custom code will
> be overwritten’ with following options:
>
> - Yes, re generate the entity - This will just regenerate your entity. Tip: This can be forced by passing a --regenerate flag when
>   running the sub-generator
> - Yes, add more fields and relationships - This will give you questions to add more fields and relationships
> - Yes, remove fields and relationships - This will give you questions to remove existing fields and relationships from the entity
> - No, exit - This will exist the sub-generator without changing anything

See:

- https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/#updating-an-existing-entity
- https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#-importing-a-jdl-file

Comment: Whao, thanks you so much for your support, that's exactly what i need.